# Architecture for Crystal reports integration with third party app

Tags: node.js, crystal-reports

Ok, here is the thing,
I have RESTAPIs in node js with mysql as a rdbms.
I'm having reports in my project and want to use Crystal reports.
I'm confused between crystal reports and crystal server.
My understanding is, I can design reports in SAP Crystal reports tool and than this tool must expose some APIs so that my Nodejs APIs can pass parametes and get reports back.

Am I thinking in correct way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite. Crystal reports libraries (API) can be hosted in an ASP.Net application which you'll need to write. From your node.js application you can pass parameters to your asp.net application and generate your reports.

Alternatively, if you have SAP Crystal Server you can use the SAP Business Intelligence Platform RESTful Web Services to interact with hosted reports.

The Crystal report libraries do not themselves contain an http API.

Comment: So if I'm not wrong,If I dont want host ASP.Net app what I can do is, Desing and Create reports in SAP crystal reports tool and than in SAP BussinessObjects BI platform repositories I can have those reports and than from SAP BOBI platform RESTful Web services I can access those reports.

Comment: True. Do you have access to SAP BOBI?